# Django - object.id in {% static %} tag not working

Tags: django, templates, static

I have stumbled upon a very weird thing. I am using Django 2.0.7

Having the following code in my template:

```
<img src="{% static 'external_page/assets/img/profile_pics/'|add:instructor.id|add:'.jpg' %}">
```

On deployment it returns (**which is wrong**):

```
<img src="/static/.jpg">
```

However if I for instance would change:

```
|add:instructor.id
```

To:

```
|add:instructor.first_name
```

It works as it should, but with first_name instead of id.

Even weirder is that not long before this, I have the following code.

```
...onclick="window.location='{% url 'profile' instructor.id %}'"
```

Which works fine.

Here is the whole code segment for a more holistic view:

**template.html**

```
<div class="team">
    <div class="row row-instructor">
        {% for instructor in instructors %}
            <div class="card card-signup col-md-4" data-background-color="orange" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location='{% url 'profile' instructor.id %}'">
                <div class="team-player">
                    <img src="{% static 'external_page/assets/img/profile_pics/'|add:instructor.id|add:'.jpg' %}" alt="Thumbnail Image" class="rounded-circle img-fluid img-raised">
                    <h4 class="title">{{ instructor.first_name }} {{instructor.last_name}}</h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `instructor.id` is an integer. and you're trying to concatenate it with string, even in templates, this will not work.

you can use `slugify` to convert it to string, or you can create your own tag function.

try this:

```
{% with instructor.id|slugify as id %}
<img src="{% static 'external_page/assets/img/profile_pics/'|add:id|add:'.jpg' %}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the suggested solution actually does not work. Are there any other filters that come to mind that might resolve it?

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: Oh never mind, I made a mistake. It worked, I will give you a green check mark.